# How do I share/bind @StateObject between SwiftUI views?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following `SwiftUI` `View` "PaletteBar":

```
struct PaletteBar: View {

    final class State: ObservableObject {
        @Published var selectedColor: Color? = .black
        @Published var isEraserSelected = false
    }

    private enum Constants {
        static let colors: [Color] = [.black, .white, .blue, .green, .yellow, .red]
        static let eraserColor: Color = .black.opacity(0.7)
    }

    // MARK: - Properties

    @ObservedObject var state = State()

    // MARK: - Body

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            PaletteItem(color: Constants.eraserColor, isSelected: Binding(
                get: { state.isEraserSelected },
                set: {
                    state.isEraserSelected = $0
                    state.selectedColor = $0 ? nil : state.selectedColor
                }
            ))
            .overlay { Image(systemName: "pencil.slash") }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

            ForEach(Constants.colors, id: \.self) { color in
                PaletteItem(color: color, isSelected: Binding(
                    get: { state.selectedColor == color },
                    set: {
                        state.selectedColor = $0 ? color : nil
                        state.isEraserSelected = $0 ? false : state.isEraserSelected
                    }
                ))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This stores the state in an `@ObservedObject`. I would like to pass this state up the hierarchy e.g `PaletteBar` is a sub view of `AnnotateImageToolbar`:

```
struct AnnotateImageToolbar: View {

    final class State: ObservableObject {
        @Published var selectedColor: Color? = .black
        @Published var isEraserSelected = false
    }

    private enum Constants {
        static let spacing: CGFloat = 12.0
        static let backgroundColor: Color = .black.opacity(0.7)
        static let colorsInsets = EdgeInsets(top: 12.0, leading: 16.0, bottom: 0.0, trailing: 16.0)
        static let sliderInsets = EdgeInsets(top: 0.0, leading: 16.0, bottom: 12.0, trailing: 16.0)
        static let radius: CGFloat = 8.0
    }

    // MARK: - State

    @StateObject var state = State()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: Constants.spacing) {
            PaletteBar()
                .padding(Constants.colorsInsets)

            ZStack {
                SizeBar()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 12.0)
                BrushSizeSlider()
            }
            .padding(Constants.sliderInsets)
        }
        .background(Constants.backgroundColor)
        .clipShape(RoundedCorners(radius: Constants.radius, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight]))
    }

}
```

Here I create an identical state object `@StateObject var state = State()`. Is there a way to bind the values from the state in `PaletteBar` to the state in `AnnotateImageToolbar`? Or Should I be creating a single state object and injecting it into each view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject it as environment object, like

```
@StateObject var state = State()

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: Constants.spacing) {
      // ... other code
    }
    .background(...)
    .clipShape(...)
    .environmentObject(state)  // << here !!
```

and use it inside children:

```
struct PaletteBar: View {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @EnvironmentObject var state: State  // << injected by parent !!

// ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this generally considered a better practice than directly injecting the data model in the init method?

Comment: Yes, with this approach we inject it once and can use anywhere in hierarchy with just declared wrapper, say once on 100th level. Imaging how we would transerfer it at that level via inits.